# how to dealloc NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray, alloc

I call createTableData from viewDidLoad. What I don't understand is I'm doing an alloc for a NSMutableDictionary but I don't understand why that object is not released from memory-despite the release.
I do see memory leaks and Leaks seems to point at this section of code.
Can someone point me to a url where I might be able to read/understand what I should be doing versus what I am doing? I just can't seem to see where I've gone wrong here.

```
- (void)createTableData {
 NSMutableArray *toolList;
 toolList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [toolList addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
     initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Some title",@"name",
          @"1",@"whatViewController",
          @"",@"url",
          @"some_icon.jpg",@"picture",
          @"some detail text",@"detailText",nil]];
 toolData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:toolList,nil];
 [toolList release];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [toolData release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [toolList addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
     initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Some title",@"name",
          @"1",@"whatViewController",
          @"",@"url",
          @"some_icon.jpg",@"picture",
          @"some detail text",@"detailText",nil]];
```

In this line your add NSMutableDictionary object to array and not releasing it. Correct code would be (using class method that already returns autoreleased object):

```
 [toolList addObject:[NSMutableDictionary 
     dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Some title",@"name",
          @"1",@"whatViewController",
          @"",@"url",
          @"some_icon.jpg",@"picture",
          @"some detail text",@"detailText",nil]];
```

or explicitly autorelease your temporary dictionary:

```
[toolList addObject:[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
     initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Some title",@"name",
          @"1",@"whatViewController",
          @"",@"url",
          @"some_icon.jpg",@"picture",
          @"some detail text",@"detailText",nil] autorelease]];
```

Comment: I also found this article which basically explains what you've provided: http://www.memo.tv/memory_management_with_objective_c_cocoa_iphone